# More efficient ways of doing this

Tags: python, optimization

```
for i in vr_world.getNodeNames():
    if i != "_error_":
         World[i] = vr_world.getChild(i)
```

vr_world.getNodeNames() returns me a gigantic list, vr_world.getChild(i) returns a specific type of object.

This is taking a long time to run, is there anyway to make it more efficient? I have seen one-liners for loops before that are supposed to be faster. Ideas?

Comment: `.getNodeNames()` is only run once when you enter the `for` loop, so if that takes a while, fix that (if possible).  Regardless of how you go about it (e.g. list comprehensions--the one-liners you refer to), presumably you're going to have to get the data that function kicks out somehow.

Comment: Have you run your code through a profiler to find out what *part* of this is slow?

Comment: Yes, I think there is nothing wrong here. I will have to explore the functions behind getNodeNames

Comment: @Daenyth: Is there something that does that in the Python stdlib?  I'd probably just use `time.time()`'s...though on something this simple with trivial python code and two black-box functions it's not like there's much debate as to what it could be.

Comment: @Daenyth: I will take a look on that. Do you have any profiler recommendations for python 2.4?

Comment: @relima: Have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#ProfilingCode . Also, if you can post the definition of the functions you are calling, we may be able to identify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kaloyan suggests using a generator.  Here's why that may help.

If `getNodeNames()` builds a list, then your loop is basically going over the list twice:  once to build it, and once when you iterate over the list.

If `getNodeNames()` is a generator, then your loop doesn't ever build the list; instead of creating the item and adding it to the list, it creates the item and yields it to the caller.

Whether or not this helps is contingent on a couple of things.  First, it has to be *possible* to implement `getNodeNames()` as a generator.  We don't know anything about the implementation details of that function, so it's not possible to say if that's the case.  Next, the number of items you're iterating over needs to be pretty big.

Of course, none of this will have any effect at all if it turns out that the time-consuming operation in all of this is `vr_world.getChild()`.  That's why you need to profile your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make it faster than what you have there. Yes, you can put the whole thing on one line but that will not make it any faster. The bottleneck obviously is `getNodeNames()`. If you can make it a generator, you will start populating the `World` dict with results sooner (if that matters to you) and if you make it filter out the `"_error_"` values, you will not have the deal with that at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
World = dict((i, vr_world.getChild(i)) for i in vr_world.getNodeNames() if i != "_error_")
```

This is a one-liner, but not necessarily much faster than your solution...

Comment: Is that actually more efficient or just more compact?

Comment: It really didn't make matters any better - or worse. Maybe it is in the getChild where the problem really is.

Comment: @GWW, a generator expression will _normally_ be 10% to 100% faster than an equivalent `for` loop, though I've seen cases where they're slower.

Comment: That's good to know.  That could be why some of my file parsing code takes forever thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a filter and a map, however I don't know if this would be any faster:

```
valid = filter(lambda i: i != "_error_", vr_world.getNodeNames())
World = map(lambda i: vr_world.getChild(i), valid)
```

Also, as you'll see a lot around here, profile first, and then optimize, otherwise you may be wasting time. You have two functions there, maybe they are the slow parts, not the iteration.

Comment: Sadly, in python, `filter`/`map` solutions are almost always slower than list comprehensions.

Comment: if speed is a factor in the first line: `valid = filter('_error_'.__eq__, vr_world.getNodeNames())`

Comment: Also, lambda functions are slower than regular ones or, as in the case above, inline logic.

Comment: and for a `huge` list, you should _really_ be using `ifilter` and `imap` from itertools to process it lazily and not have to keep everything in memory at once. this can be a huge timesaver for really large lists.